# Understanding Option Method

Tags: scala, scala-option

For the following `map` signature, am I reading it correctly?

```
   object OptionImpl extends Option {
        def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B]
    }
```

source - [FP in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/)

`[B]` means only objects of type `B` can call this function

`f: A => B` means that  it accepts 1 argument, a function, that returns the same type `B`

I'm fuzzy on a concrete example of this function.

Comment: I don't see any `OptionImpl` in the whole book, and it makes absolutely no sense to subclass `Option` that way. There are only two subclasses of `Option`: `Some` and `None`.

Comment: @Daniel, I'm referring to Chapter 4, Exercise 1 on page 58. `Implement the above functions on the trait, 'Option'`
 `trait Option[+A] {
def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] ... }` OptionImpl is the name I'm giving to my implementation of `Option`

Comment: For the purposes of an exercise, "implement" doesn't mean you need to subclass anything. Just copy the `Option[+A]` trait and write the code there.

Comment: @Kevin You should probably implement them on the trait itself, but, if you decide to implement it on subclasses, `Option` should be extended by the singleton `None` and the class `Some`, and only by them. Your `OptionImpl` would, then, be equivalent to `None`, and a `Some` class would still be required, and a corresponding implementation on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B` is just a wildcard (i.e. generic).  It just says that these two types are the same:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B]
                   ^          ^
```

That is, it says: if you pass me a function that converts `A`s to `B`s, I will give you back an `Option` that may contain a `B` (where `B` can be any type).

Comment: Thanks, Rex. Could you please give me an example of how an `Option` object would use the `map` function?

Comment: @Kevin - No, because I don't have the book.  But if `OptionImpl` were an `Option[String]`, you might use it as `OptionImpl.map(s => s.length)` to get an `Option[Int]` back (which would contain an `Int` if `OptionImpl` actually contained a string).

Comment: Would you expect this method to consist of `if (A is empty) None else f`? Your `Option[Int]` example helped me, but I'm trying to write an implementation of the trait in a generic way: `trait Option[+A] {
 def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] }`

Comment: @Kevin you can find solutions and hints for the exercises in the [book github repo](https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala). Enjoy your reading!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very useful link http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/ on usage of Option.

If you have scenario like this

```
 option match {
   case None => None
   case Some(x) => Some(foo(x))
 }
```

use

```
option.map(foo(_))
```

Another example

```
def processBody(contentType: String): String = {
 .....
}

val body: Option[String] = 
   headers.get("Content-Type").map(processBody(_))
```

I assumed here that headers.get returns an Option.